# How to pull from a database to make an FAQ page?

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, I have a Database with three tables.  Q&A, Categories, and IDs.  Categories holds categories, Q&A has the questions and answers, and IDs has the IDs of various categories and the questions attached to them.  How can I pull from the database so that I get a category, and then a loop of the Q&A that falls into that category?

```
function print_categories() {
global $MySQL;


if (($categories = $MySQL->select_all("SELECT * FROM QandA_wiki.categories")) !== false) {
foreach ($categories as $citem) {
$counter = 1;
print"<div id=\"categories_start\" style=\"width:424px; margin:0 auto;\">\n";
print"<div id=\"category\" >\n";
print"<h2> {$citem['description']}</h2>";
print  "<div class=\"col-lg-12 footerLine\"><hr /></div>";
    if (($questions = $MySQL->select_all("SELECT * FROM QandA_wiki.qanda")) !== false) {
    foreach ($questions as $qitem) {
        print"<div id=\"question_number\" >\n";
        print"<div id=\"questions\" >\n";
        print"<p>#: {$counter} -<strong>{$qitem['question']}</strong></p>";

        print"</div>\n";
        print"<p>     {$qitem['answer']}</p>";
        print  "<div class=\"col-lg-12 footerLine\"><hr /></div>";


        print"</div>\n";

        print"<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>\n";
        print"<br />\n";
        $counter=$counter+1;
        }
      }
print"</div>\n";
print"</div>\n";

print"<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>\n";
print"<br />\n";

}}}}
```

Comment: You want to take a look at `LEFT JOIN`. With this you query the `Q&A` table, `LEFT JOIN` it with the `Categories` table then have a `WHERE` clause on the `Categories` table. From there, you can just iterate over your findings.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your table/column names but this is a rough idea of a `LEFT JOIN` that might get what you need

```
SELECT QandA_wiki.qanda.*, QandA_wiki.qanda.id, QandA_wiki.qanda.name_of_your_column
FROM QandA_wiki.qanda
LEFT JOIN QandA_wiki.categories
ON QandA_wiki.qanda.category_id = QandA_wiki.categories.id // This is a guess here...likely will need to modify
WHERE QandA_wiki.categories.name_of_your_column = name_you_want; // This where clause does the filtering as you needed
```

Also, I'm not sure what your `$MySQL` function does but in `mysqli` it would look something like this (where `$link` is your database connection info):

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,
    "SELECT QandA_wiki.qanda.*, QandA_wiki.qanda.id, QandA_wiki.qanda.name_of_your_column
    FROM QandA_wiki.qanda
    LEFT JOIN QandA_wiki.categories
    ON QandA_wiki.qanda.category_id = QandA_wiki.categories.id
    WHERE QandA_wiki.categories.name_of_your_column = name_you_want;");
```

Then you can just iterate over `$query`. You should consider using prepared statements if you're grabbing the category via user input. I hope this gets you going in the correct direction